# How to define an object inside a for loop for excel vba

Tags: vba, object, excel, for-loop

I want to import data from multiple workbooks, all from the same sheet index (3). 
I'm new to vba, and I figured out how to open multiple files up, and also to copy data from one sheet to another sheet in a different workbook for a single file, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that for multiple files.
I highlighted where the error is, it tells me "object doesn't support this property or method"

Could you please help?
Thanks

```
Sub dataimport()

' Set Vars
Dim ArbinBook As Workbook, DataBook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Caption As String
Dim ArbinFile As Variant, DataFile As Variant


' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set DataBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get Arbin workbook
Caption = "Please select an input file"
    ' To set open destination:
    ' ChDrive ("E")
    ' ChDir ("E:\Chapters\chap14")
    ' With Application

'Set "arbinfile" as variant, the "true" at end makes it into an array
ArbinFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , Caption, , True)

'Exit when canceled
If Not IsArray(ArbinFile) Then
    MsgBox "No file was selected."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = DataBook.Sheets(1)


'Open for every integer i selected in the array "arbinfile"
For i = LBound(ArbinFile) To UBound(ArbinFile)
        Set ArbinBook = Workbooks.Open(ArbinFile(i))


targetSheet.Range("A2", "G150").Value = ArbinBook.Sheets(3).Range("A2", "G150").Value

   **ERROR at the line above**   

        Workbooks(DataSheet).Activate                        'Reactivate the data book
        Worksheets(1).Activate                               'Reactivate the data sheet
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy _
           after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Workbooks(ArbinFile(1)).Activate                 'Reactivate the arbin book(i)


        ArbinBook.Close

Next i
Beep

End Sub
```

Comment: try it without using `.value` on either of the range calls

Comment: Is the error happening at the beginning of the loop, or when you are trying to copy the range? (the line above or below where your **ERROR HERE** appears?)

Comment: Hi, sorry the error appears at the after the line "targetsheet.range..."

Answer (score 1):

My instinct tells me that `ArbinBook.Sheets(3)` is a Chart-sheet, not a WorkSheet (or, at least, it is something other than a WorkSheet). It might be hidden as well, but it will still be indexed as (3).

If so, change `Sheets(3)` to `Worksheets(3)`.

**Added**: BTW If true, this also demonstrates why using index-numbers is unreliable. If at all possible, refer to a worksheet by its name. (I appreciate that this may not always be possible.)

**Added** (from comments) There is nothing named `DataSheet` in your code. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module to indicate all such errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks, the error is now different, says "automation error"

Comment: So when it produces the error what line does it take you to? **Added** but the 1 in this line `Workbooks(ArbinFile(1)).Activate` should be **i**.

Comment: Okay thanks, i fixed that. but the error is still at the same line as before

Comment: There is nothing named `DataSheet` in your code. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module to indicate all such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line `Set ArbinBook = Workbooks.Open(ArbinFile(i))`

to `Set ArbinBook = Workbooks(arbinfile(i))`

I could be wrong, but I think it's trying to set your workbook object to become the action of opening another workbook, instead of labeling it as the workboook.

Comment: `Workbooks.Open("somefile")` opens a workbook and then `ArbinBook` will refer to this book. Your second statement assumes that the workbook is already open.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Multiple()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim exlApp As Excel.Application
Dim exlWb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim exlWb2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim exlWb3 As Excel.Workbook
Dim exlWs1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim exlWs2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim exlWs3 As Excel.Worksheet
Set exlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set exlWb1 = exlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\yourpath1\file1.xls")
Set exlWb2 = exlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\yourpath2\file2.xls")
Set exlWb3 = exlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\yourpath3\file3.xls")
Set exlWs1 = exlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set exlWs2 = exlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set exlWs3 = exlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
exlWb1.Activate
exlWb2.Activate
exlWb3.Activate
'code
exlWb.Close savechanges:=True
exlWb.Close savechanges:=True
exlWb.Close savechanges:=True
Set exlWs1 = Nothing
Set exlWs2 = Nothing
Set exlWs3 = Nothing
Set exlWb1 = Nothing
Set exlWb2 = Nothing
Set exlWb3 = Nothing
exlApp.Quit
Set exlApp = Nothing
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You've hard-coded what ought to ordinarily be done in a loop, and require 1/3 as many objects in memory... not to mention, this method doesn't work if you have more than 3 workbooks, or less than 3 workbooks, you constantly need to add new `Workbook` and `Worksheet` variables, etc.